# How find suffix in tree

Tags: java, oop, suffix-tree, suffix

i am trying to make basic object oriented suffix tree console program and i dont know how to make boolean suffix(String s) method. My actual suffix method doesn't work properly. Finally it should looks like :

[image: suffix tree with # as leafs]

Node is for object, SuffixTree create tree and have methods for that tree, TestTree have main method for testing

### Node

```
package trie3;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class Node{

   private final char currentValue;
   Map<Character,Node> children;
   Node(){
     this.currentValue = '#';
     this.children = new HashMap<Character,Node>();
   }    
   Node(char currentValue){ 
     this.currentValue = currentValue;
     this.children = new HashMap<Character,Node>();
   }       
   char getValue(){
     return this.currentValue;
   }
   void addChild(Node c){
    this.children.put(c.getValue(),c);
   }
   boolean hasChild(Node c){
    return this.children.containsKey(c.getValue());
   }  
   Node getChild(Node c){
     return this.children.get(c.getValue());
   }
  public String toString(){
    char currentValue = this.getValue();
    StringBuffer keys = new StringBuffer();
    for(char key:this.children.keySet()){
      keys.append("Current key:"+key+"\n");
    }
     return "Current value:"+currentValue+"\n"+
        "Keys:"+keys.toString(); 
   }
  }
```

### SuffixTree

```
package trie3;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import trie3.Node;
public class SuffixTree{
  private Node root;

  private void log(Object l){
     System.out.println(l);
  }
  /*
   * Helper method that initializes the suffix tree
   */
  private Node createSuffixTree(String source,Node root){
    for(int i=1;i<source.length();i++){
      Node parent = new Node(source.charAt(i));
      if(root.hasChild(parent)){
        parent = root.getChild(parent);
      }
      Node current = parent;            
      for(int j=i+1;j<source.length();j++){
        Node temp = new Node(source.charAt(j));
    if(current.hasChild(temp)){
      temp = current.getChild(temp);
    }else{
      current.addChild(temp);
    }
        current = temp; 
      }
      root.addChild(parent);    
    }
    return root;         
  }

  /*
   Creates the suffix tree from the given string
   */
  public SuffixTree(String source){
    this.root = createSuffixTree(source,new Node()); // jj to je vychozi s # jj jo
  }   

  void printMap(Map<Character,Node> map){ // vytiskne vsechny znaky potomku daneho suffixu takze hahaa -- pokud budes od n tak to bude a h a a # tusim teda
     for(char c:map.keySet()){ 
      System.out.println("Current node has child: " +c);
    }
  }  

  boolean infix(String target){ // infix method
    Map<Character,Node> rootChildren = this.root.children;
   for(char c:target.toCharArray()){
      if(rootChildren.containsKey(c)){
        rootChildren = rootChildren.get(c).children;
      }else{
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

    boolean suffix(String target){ // like infix but last char must be leaf
    Map<Character,Node> rootChildren = this.root.children;

   for(int i=0;i<target.length()-1;i++){
       printMap(rootChildren);
       char c = target.charAt(i);
      if(rootChildren.containsKey(c)){
        rootChildren = rootChildren.get(c).children;
      }else if(rootChildren == null){
          System.out.println("hash");
        return true;

      }else{
      return false;
      }
    }
return false;
  }
```

### testTree

```
public class testTree {
       public static void main(String[] args){
    SuffixTree sTree = new SuffixTree("hahaa"); 

    //test suffix
   if(sTree.infix("ha")){ 
       System.out.println(":)");
   }
   else{
       System.out.println(":(");
   }

      if(sTree.suffix("ha")){ // true only for a,ha,haa,ahaa
       System.out.println(":)");
   }
   else{
       System.out.println(":(");
   }
   //test substring

    //  sTree.printMap();
   }
}
```

Comment: And what is your specific question we should help with? I just see a lot of code and some not so clear requirements.

Comment: You should improve your question. Try to explain what should your method do. Why it returns boolean? Substring methods usually returns some String, maybe you just choosed bad name for the method, so it does not have sense without explanation what are you trying achieve.

Comment: A main method running this code would be useful as well

Comment: if its substring in tree it should return true , false otherwise.

Comment: so the suffix method should be true for any valid substring or only for a suffix or the original word?

if is the first option use the fact that a valid substring is the prefix of one suffix. For instance "ah" is the prefix of "ahaa"